# How to set vim as default cscope editor?

Tags: linux, vim, cscope

`cscope` opens my files in `vi`. Is there a way to change it so that it opens files in `vim` instead ?

**Edit**: I tried:

```
export CSCOPE_EDITOR=vim
```

For some weird reason, if I type `:help` on the file opened, it shows `vim help` which indicates it is opened in `vim` but it doesn't seem to read my `.vimrc`. How can I make it read my `.vimrc` ?

**Edit 2: Machine/tool info**

```
[user@machine] $  printenv | grep -i cscope    
CSCOPE_EDITOR=vim

[user@machine] $  vim --version
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.0 (2006 May 7, compiled Jul 10 2012 08:48:09)
Included patches: 1, 3-4, 7-9, 11, 13-17, 19-26, 29-31, 34-44, 47, 50-56, 58-64, 66-73, 75, 77-92, 94-107, 109, 202, 234-237

[user@machine] $  cscope -V
cscope: version 15.5
```

Comment: try `EDITOR=vim cscope`

Comment: Nope , that doesn't work.

Comment: I have both `EDITOR=vim` and `VISUAL=vim` set in my environment, and `cscope` uses `vim` and runs with my setup.  However, unsetting either or both also leaves it running `vim`, so that's not conclusive.  Looking at the strings in the program, `EDITOR` appears but `VISUAL` does not; there is also `CSCOPE_EDITOR`.  All of which is not much help.  Did you build `cscope`?  Which version are you running (`-V`; I'm running 15.7a that I built on a Mac)?  I do have `EXINIT` set, but `vim` is being run with settings that are not in `EXINIT`.

Comment: vi is almost certainly vim.

Comment: Alternative: use cscope inside of vim instead of the other way around. See `:h cscope` and `:h :cscope`

Comment: It is working now, but I still don't know what the problem was.
For some weird reason, my files were getting opened in vim, but it wasn't reading my old .vimrc. I tried deleting the cscope.out file and re-creating it and then opening the search results, they were still opening in vim but the .vimrc wasn't still being read.
In a new workspace, I tried the whole thing again and now cscope files do open up in vim, .vimrc being properly read.

Comment: It seems that i have the same problem as you describe. How did you fix it?

Comment: For Vim users on Windows at least (I don't know about Linux): http://stackoverflow.com/a/35024192/1245420

Answer (score 12):

Just make sure that your `.vimrc` is at the same location as `.bashrc`.
And then in `.bashrc`, add the following line:

```
export CSCOPE_EDITOR=vim
```

This worked for me.

Comment: Explanation of what this does and why it works would be good.